# How to initialize a fixed array to a value with Raku

Tags: raku

It may be silly but I haven't found a good solution in the documentation about how to initialize a fixed array, or multidimensional array on an easy way without iterating.

```
my @array[10] = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
my @grid[100;100];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd probably use the `xx` operator. Something like this :

```
my @array[10] = 0 xx 10;
my @grid[100;100] = [0 xx 100] xx 100;
```

Comment: Great, I didn't know that operator. Pretty useful though.